# Laravel 4 - Writing complex queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could convert this to L4's query language.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ( user_one = $id AND user_one_deleted = 0 ) OR ( user_two = $id AND user_two_deleted = 0 )
```

I have had a look here

```
http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres
```

But it doesnt really show what im trying to do.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  <?php
  DB::table('messages')
    ->where(function($query) use ($id) {
      $query->where('user_one', $id)
        ->where('user_one_deleted', 0);
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($id) {
      $query->where('user_two', $id)
        ->where('user_two_deleted', 0);
  });
  ?>
```

It **is** in L4 docs: http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres

Comment: Parameter grouping is in the docs, but if you're unfamiliar with PHP closure syntax, it isn't much help if you have dynamic values in your conditions.